# Java Binary Tree recursive Insert

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I am new to Java. Please help me understand the below code, how the pointer is moving from left to right. This code is working perfectly. I just want to know the working.Lets say if we insert 20,30,10,35,9 .How pointer moves from 10 which is left of root 20 to 35 which is right of root 20, node 30 .Shouldn't it be always hanging to left and right of most recent node added as per the code.

```
    class Node {
    Node right, left;
    int data = 0;
    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void insert(int value) {
        if (value <= data) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new Node(value);
            } else {
                left.insert(value);
            }
        } else {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new Node(value);
            } else {
                right.insert(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: left and right will be null by default if not assigned

Comment: The pointer doesn't move across the tree, only up and down the current branch, based on the value being inserted...

Comment: You could add a print statement within the method, or learn about the debugger to really figure out how it works

Comment: Added debugger and checked, everything is getting added to left or right of root creating an unbalanced tree

Comment: Maybe you should show your main method for how you are actually inserting data

Comment: public class runner {
  

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Node new_node=new Node(0);
  new_node.insert(5);
  new_node.insert(4);
  new_node.insert(9);
  new_node.insert(3);
  new_node.insert(7);
  new_node.display();
   
  

 }

}

Comment: Why is that unbalanced? You should have a root with 2 nodes to the left and right. On the right side, the 7 is left leaf of 9, with the parent of 9 being 5.

Comment: Yes looks right . Got it now .Thanks. Is there a way I may create just               Node new_node=new Node();   and pass values later in insert , here I am passing (0) while creating object in main.

Comment: You could add a no-arg constructor with a default value, sure

Comment: How I will call in that case.   Node new_node=new Node();  new_node.insert(5);  In this case first or root node will always be 0 which is not expected.

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting. A Node needs a value. Either `Node(int data)` or `Node()`, which implictly sets `data = 0`. Perhaps you can create a separate post explaning what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer moves correctly as the check `if (value <= data) {` decides which way to go, if the incoming value is less then or equal to the current node value then it will move to the left otherwise to the right. After the move it again calls insert over the left or right node.

Comment: Does it mean it will always remain left side or right side of the root (i.e first node) only up and down  of current branch.

Comment: Yes, if the incoming node is less than or equal to the root node it will be on the left otherwise it will be on right of root node.

Comment: Ok thanks, just one more question ,If I am not wrong       (value <= data) is new node value compared with current node data .But where we are comparing with root or first node data to know which side to insert of root.

Comment: Root Node will be the first Node you will start your program execution with.